# Will stretching help me have lean, shapely muscles?

Tags: physiology, natural-remedies, physical-fitness

I read that after exercising, we should stretch our muscles so that they won't be bulky but instead be long and lean. Is this true?

Edit: The question is more about aesthetics than whether stretching is healthy. So if I wanted to have toned but lean muscles, would it be helpful if I stretch my muscles after exercising?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for biology.se than skeptics. In fact, it's already answered on fitness.se: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/455/should-i-stretch-after-exercise

Comment: Welcome to  Skeptics.SE! Please visit the Help Center for information about this site and its standards for questions. For starters, to make this question fit, you would need to say where you read this (including a link, or enough information for others to find it), and you need to have seen it somewhere notable (like a newspaper, magazine, or popular website - not your friend's blog).

Comment: Please read the edit.My question is actually more on aesthetics,and not about whether stretching is beneficial to the body.So it's quitec different from the questions that have already been asked.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).